# Laravel vue axios is action method and csrf needed for ajax forms

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I am posting a ajax from in Laravel using axios and vue, I have a `@click="postData"` button in the form that toggles a axios post request:

```
postData() {
      axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: appJS.base_url + '/comment',
          responseType: 'json',
          data: comData
        })
        .then(function(response) {

        })
```

But do I still need to add the **action**, **method** and **csrf** to my form?

```
<form action="{{ url('/comment') }}" method="POST">
{{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

vs

```
<form></form>
```

Everything works fine just using `<form></form>` but I wonder if there are any pros/cons?

I am making a ajax call in the background since I dont want the whole page to reload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely don't need `action` and `method` attributes on `form` tag, because they are already defined on your axios call.

As for the `csrf_field()`, you probably still need it, because Laravel has a preconfigured middleware called `VerifyCsrfToken`. But it depends if you use it or not.

Comment: I just saw that this was included in bootstrap.js
``window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
  window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
  console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}``
so I guess I dont need to include it then coz it already take it from the page meta?

Comment: @Kiow Yes. If you have a meta tag with your `csrf-token`, there's no need to include it on your form.

Answer (score 0):

you can using event form in vuejs, you need't using ajax, you can try the following code, but if laravel + vuejs, need add Enable CORS for a Single Route in laravel:https://gist.github.com/drewjoh/43ba206c1cde9ace35de154a5c84fc6d

```js
export default{
        data(){
            return{
                title:"Form Register",
            }
        },
        methods:{
           register(){
                this.axios.post("http://localhost:8888/form-register",this.formdata).then((response) => {
                       console.log(response);
                      
                  });
                    
            },
 
        }
    }
```

```html
 <form action="" method="post" v-on:submit.prevent="register">
    <div class="panel-heading">{{title}}</div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Register</button>
      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-success">Reset</button>                  
    </div>
 </form>
```